# Is there an interface of read barrier in CoreCLR's standalone GC?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, zgc, azul-zing

It seems that there's no interface of read barrier in CoreCLR.

Recently I have implemented a pauseless GC in C. Here's my project:
https://github.com/LizBing/Uboa-Garbage-Collector
I tried customing a standalone GC library which can be used in .net. As we all know, one of the most important parts of a pauseless GC algorithm is the read barrier. However, I couldn't find any interface I can implement to reach my target.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

There is none. Standalone GP API in .NET runtime misses some important capabilities, including:

- API for object scanning ([Issue #12809](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12809))
- API for setting up write barrier

And there are no read barriers at all yet so no API here too.

The closest I could get is my https://github.com/kkokosa/UpsilonGC. It's a little outdated but AFAIK "local GC" project is no longer developed since that times neither.

Comment: Thanks! I read your blog and it helps a lot.I wonder is there more detailed information about implementing a standalone GC for .net?

Comment: Unfortunately, the most detailed information I am aware of are... my articles and talks. That's super niche topic :(